# How to code: if loading of a file/model is possible, skip running it again

Tags: r

How to complement the code in a way that if loading of a file/model is possible, then skip running and saving the model again.

```
load("model.RData")    
model = brm(bf(pt_overall_outpatient ~ predictor), data = data)
save(model, file = "model.Rdata")
```

Comment: You should just use a basic control flow block with something like `if ( file.exists("model.RData") ) { ... }  else { ... }`. See `help("if")` and `help("file.exists")`

Comment: Thank you a lot!